# How to give horizontal line using from HTML without using webview

Tags: android

I have textview I want to give horizontal line after some text.

For example,

```
String line1="Hello Developer";
String line2-"Bye All";

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(line1+"<hr>"+line2);
```

But `<hr>` tag is not working here.
How to show using fromHtml without using webview.

Comment: use <br> instead of <hr>

Comment: @Palakp have you found a solution? I need this horizontal line (in only one textview...)

Answer (score 0):

Because `<hr>` is not supported tag. Below are the **Tags Supported by Html.fromHtml()**

```
<a> (supports attribute "href")
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div>
<em>
<font> (supports attributes "color" and "face")
<i>
<img> (supports attribute "src". Note: you have to include an ImageGetter to handle retrieving a Drawable for this tag)
<p>
<small>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

Answer (score 0):

HR tag is not supported in Android outside WebView.

try following solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Hello Developer" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Bye All" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No, I can't use view. I want all in one textview.